# Play video inside UIView clipping to views bounds

Tags: swift, uiview, avfoundation, avplayerlayer

I want to play a video inside a UIView making It clipped to the views bounds.

The video is stored in my Xcode project and it plays fine but it doesn't anchor correctly to the view bounds.

Here's the code:

```
class PlaceHolderVideoView : UIView{

let containerImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "VideoContainerView"), contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)



override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    setUpUI()
    
    setUpPlayer()
    
    
    
}

fileprivate func setUpUI(){
    
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    addSubview(containerImageView)
    containerImageView.fillSuperview()
    
}



fileprivate func setUpPlayer(){

    let urlPathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dance", ofType: "mp4")

    if let videoURL = urlPathString{
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoURL)

        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)


        playerLayer.frame = self.containerImageView.frame

        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        player.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `clipsToBounds`.

```
class PlaceHolderVideoView: UIView {
    //...
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        clipsToBounds = true
        //...
    }
    //...
    fileprivate func setUpPlayer() {
        //..
        playerLayer.frame = containerImageView.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it make the player clips to bounds but the video played is not entirely shown, it is partially hided, do you know how I can make also the video fit perfectly inside the view's bounds?

Comment: Check the update, you need to use the `containerImageView.bounds` to set frame.